# Verificar se um objeto possui todos os valores iguais a outro objeto, e filtrar array com base nesta condição

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar uma condicional a partir de filtros dinâmicos.
Supomos que o filtro retornado seja esse:

```
const toFilter = { nome: 'joao', idade: 13 }
```

Significa que eu preciso retornar do meu array de dados as informações que tenham o nome igual a joão e a idade igual a 13.

Esse filtro vai se alterando dinamicamente conforme selecionado na tela, mas sempre precisa satisfazer todos os critérios.

Eu tentei criar este código:

```
 const data = [{ nome: 'maria', idade: 13, estado: 'CE' }, { nome: 'tereza', idade: 23, estado: 'SP' }, { nome: 'joao', idade: 10, estado: 'SP' }, { nome: 'joao', idade: 13, estado: 'SP' }]

     const result = data.reduce((acc, row) => {
            Object.keys(toFilter).forEach(key => {
              if (row[key] === toFilter[key]) acc.push(row);
            });
            return acc;
          }, []);
```

Só que ele filtra caso o nome seja igual a joao **ou** a idade seja igual a 13, mas era pra retornar apenas um único item que é onde tem o nome igual a joão **e** a idade igual a 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `forEach` só percorre as chaves do filtro e compara uma a uma, e se encontrar apenas uma delas igual, adiciona nos resultados.

Mas o que você quer é verificar se **todas** as chaves do filtro são iguais, então precisa testar todos e só depois adicionar.

Uma alternativa é usar o método `every`, que retorna `true` se todos os elementos satisfazem uma condição:

```js
const toFilter = { nome: 'joao', idade: 13 };
const data = [
    { nome: 'maria', idade: 13, estado: 'CE' },
    { nome: 'tereza', idade: 23, estado: 'SP' },
    { nome: 'joao', idade: 10, estado: 'SP' },
    { nome: 'joao', idade: 13, estado: 'SP' }
];

const result = [], keys = Object.keys(toFilter);
for (const item of data) {
    // se todos os valores do filtro são iguais ao do elemento, adiciona nos resultados
    if (keys.every(filtro => toFilter[filtro] == item[filtro])) {
        result.push(item);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

---

É claro que também dá para fazer com `reduce`:

```js
const keys = Object.keys(toFilter);
const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (keys.every(filtro => toFilter[filtro] == item[filtro])) {
        acc.push(item);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Ou com `filter`:

```
const keys = Object.keys(toFilter);
const result = data.filter(item => keys.every(filtro => toFilter[filtro] == item[filtro]));
```

Mas pra que isso se um *loop* simples já resolve? Sem contar que `reduce` e `filter` são mais lentos, [veja](https://jsbench.me/x2ldvznt2p/1) - claro que, para poucos arrays pequenos, a diferença será insignificante (e em alguns casos pode até ser ligeiramente mais rápido), mas conforme os arrays crescem, começa a fazer diferença.

Comment: Uau, eu estava com a mente fechada para essa possibilidade do every, e também nao sabia que o reduce seria mais lento, muito obrigado, deu certinho!!!